# SfdcCore.js "Sfdc" is undefinied problem IE9

Tags: visualforce

I get the following in IE 9 when visting a page (here the login page)

```
SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

SfdcCore.js, line 71 character 160
SCRIPT5009: "Sfdc" is undefinied
VFState.js, line 1 character 1
SCRIPT5009: "Sfdc" is undefinied
```

The affect of this is an error in the console, the login does not work and also the login validation is not working. I have to switch to the compatibility mode. Then it is working.  If you don't know of a fix how can I enable the compatibility mode? Placing a meta tag into the header does not work, because it is rendered too late (IE 9 reports HTML1115 error).

See also http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Struggling-with-IE/td-p/506213

Comment: You've tagged this as Visualforce but mention a login page. If this is VF can you provide some code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am getting same error but in VFState.js and main.js.
The problem is only in production salesforce org but not in sandbox org.